# How do you alter a a snapshot of the main child in order to not create security rule problems?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

```
A = Database.database().reference().child("users");
A.observe(DataEventType.value, with: {snapshot in
```

The rules:

```
"rules": {
    "users" :
        ".read": "auth.uid != null",
         ".write": "auth.uid != null"  {
             "$uid":  {
                    "Garden" :{
                        ".read": "auth.uid != null"
                         ,".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
 }
                     "Hose": .....
                     "House": ....
```

So as you'll see the users is not being assigned a rule because it would override rules for Garden, House, Hose etc. Therefore, I want to alter the code that looks for the snapshot in A to go more directly to the childs of users, vs stopping at users and consequently not passing the security test (since users has no rules).

What comes after A.observe:

```
   for users in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
let usersObject = users.value as? [String: AnyObject]
let usersGarden = usersObject?["Garden"] as? String
let usersHose = usersObject?["Hose"] as? String
let usersHouse = usersObject?["House"]  as? String
......

let USA = UserH(Garder: usersGarden, Hose: usersHose...)
 self.users.append.

self.table.reloadData()
```

You'll see that the targets are the childs that come after uid, so a way to target them could allow me to avoid stopping at users in the snapshot A

Comment: What are you trying to do here? It appears you're reading in the entire *users* node by .value and then iterating over all of the child nodes? Once you've read the whole node then, well, you've read the whole node and then all the child data. What does 'avoid stopping at users in the snapshot A' mean?

Comment: I am doing this for 'let USA = UserH'. UserH is used in public override func tableView. The elements inside UserH are features for each user that are displayed via tableView. What did I mean by that: Well you'll see in A that it reads the users, ie it doesn't go further as something like this would: 'A = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("Garden")' The problem with stopping at users (so to speak) in the snapshot, is that I need rules for users. These rules then override the rules for a child like Garden.

Comment: *I made an edit to the rules, that I forgot when posting the question.

Comment: Again, what's being asked is unclear. The code shown in the question reads all of the users within the */users* node and then iterates over them, creating a *UserH* object and appending it to an array `self.users`. Any authenticated user *auth.uid != null* can read all of the data within the */users* node. There's nothing in the rules preventing reading of that data or 'stopping'. Can you update the question with what's being asked an include the code you're having difficulty with? Then we can take a look at try to help.

Comment: Sorry that it was not clear. This is I believe the only relevant code. The issue with the rules as they are right now is that any authenticated user can read and write data. Why is that a problem: because the rules for Garden and other childs should not be so loose( '$uid == auth.uid' for example). As is, allowing any authenticated user read and write privileges, overrides the stricter rules set for childs like Garden. Therefore, I want to write my code in a way that only deals with snapshots that go directly to childs like Garden. If this clarifies it, I'll add it to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is, the code and the rules in the question match, the code reads the users node and the rules allow any authenticated user to read that node iterate over the child data.

I believe your actual question is

> How do I get a more granular control of what can be *written* to a child
> node in Firebase using Firebase Rules

suppose we have a structure that matches your rules

```
users
   uid_0
      garden: "rose"
      hose: "green"
   uid_1
      garden: "tomato"
      hose: "black"
```

and suppose we only want to allow a user to update their own garden; other users cannot modify that users garden. e.g. uid_0 can modify only the node `/users/uid_0/garden`. uid_1 can only modify `/users/uid_1/garden` etc.

Here's a rule that lets all authenticated users read the users node but only the currently authenticated user can write to their own garden node

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
      ".write": false,
        "users" : {
          ".read": "auth != null",
            "$uid": {
              "garden": {
                ".write": "$uid === auth.uid" //only the authenticated user can write
              }
          }
        }
  }
}
```

Note that I set read and write to false at a high level and am granting access at a lower, more granular level.

So in this case, if there was another node at the same level as 'users' nobody could read or write to it.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. My only issue is, there is also a child on the same level as Garden (call it "wholikesme") that is supposed to be read: "$uid == auth.uid", not any authorized user. That is why I thought it might be best to change the code and snapshot in such a way that I can avoid having to give users a read rule.

Comment: @franktimmon Not sure I see the issue there. Only the currently auth'd user can modify his own garden node in my answer. If you have another node that you want to limit the read, move the .read rule shown in my answer to the garden node, and then set up another rule for the whoelikesme node.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks. But if I move the ".read": "auth != null", from users to the child, the snapshot won't be able to read users, right? I'll try it, but I did this before once and then I had no permission to read users. How I saw the problem is this: for the snapshot, I must have all authorized users being able to read, but for the child like Garden, read must sometimes be "$uid == auth.uid". If I use both, the users rule overrides the child rule, if I put nothing at users, the snapshot is not allow. Also (I'll google it now too), what's  benefit of === vs ==?

Comment: I just reread your comment: do you mean the other child( whoelikesme) being one leve deeper than garden? It is on the same level right now. So the only way that would make sense is if whoelikesme is a child of garden, not also a child of uid. Would garden read then not override whoelikesme read as well? Would still leave users snapshot w/o a rule though

Comment: @franktimmon It almost sounds like you're trying to use rules as a filter and that's not what they are for. If you want all users to read the */users* node then what I have in my answer will do that. It wouldn't make sense to let all users read the /users node and then deny them read access on a child node since you gave them access in the first place, right? If you have child data that should not be accessed, move it to another node where you can can control per-user access.

Comment: Filtering was not my intention with rules. But yeah that is the crux of the problem. I gave access to users just cause that was how I managed to make the code work there. The childs need to be a little safer. Moving the child nodes would then be the best option it seems. Issue is just: each child is a feature that is tied to a user, therefore it makes most sense to have them be childs under uid. Is there any other way to keep them tied to their user while moving them from under uid. Maybe on same level as users.

Comment: Sure. Pretty easy; create a node at the same level as users to store the garden data */garden_data/uid/garden: rose* then, apply whatever rules to that node - for example users can only read/write to their own node. Likewise create a node *who_likes/uid/likes_me: uid_x* and then apply appropriate rules.

Comment: hmm, interesting. Thanks. I'll try and let you know if it works.